# How to perform ElasticSearch query on records from only a certain user (Rails Tire gem)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, tire

I have a `Mongoid` model which I perform `ElasticSearch` search queries on. Very standard:

```
class ActivityLog
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  include Tire::Model::Search
  include Tire::Model::Callbacks

  field :extra, type: Hash

  belongs_to :user, :inverse_of => :activity_logs


  def self.search(params, user)
    tire.search(load: true, page: params[:page], per_page: 5) do
      query { string params[:query], default_operator: "AND" } if params[:query].present?
      sort { by :created_at, "desc" }
    end
  end
```

I am having a hard time understanding the [documentation](https://github.com/karmi/retire#activemodel-integration) on how to do more advanced stuff, and currently I'm stuck in how to work into my search query that search should be restricted to `ActivityLog` objects that belongs to the user only.

Could anyone show me how to work the user._id match requirement into the search query?

Comment: you should index the user id in the activity log, then filter on it.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But I am not sure how to do this. Could you elaborate a little bit, and maybe put it into an answer?

Comment: you have no dedicated indexing method?

Comment: I have this line: index_name("#{Rails.env}-#{Rails.application.class.to_s.downcase}-activity_logs")

Comment: well no, you are relying on defaults which makes difficult to tailor, you should read the doc, too much to say even in an sanswer

Comment: OK, I understand. But it is a "simple" relation that I want to filter by. I thought that there were many people out there who had previously needed to search for objects that only belonged to a certain user/object id...

Comment: sure but its really easy: you index the foreign key and you filter it in your query and you're good

Comment: OK, and can you show me an example on how to index a foreign key?

Comment: `indexes :user_id`, but the indexing json must match

Comment: Hmm, well not sure I am able to put the pieces from the comments together to a solution. I am asking the question because I am not so sharp in ElasticSearch. But I guess I'll just have to read up on it.

Answer (score 0):

Working with ElasticSearch, there are 2 parts: mapping and search

So, if you want to search by a field of association table (users table), right. There are many ways, but this one I often use for my project:

Inside the `ActivityLog` model

```
  mapping do
    indexes :id, type: 'integer'
    indexes :name, type: 'string', analyzer: 'snowball', boost: 5
    indexes :description, type: 'string', analyzer: 'snowball'
    indexes :description_latin, as: 'description.sanitize', type: 'string', analyzer: 'snowball'
    indexes :user_id, as: 'user.id', type: 'string', index: :not_analyzed
    indexes :user_name, as: 'user.name', type: 'string'
    indexes :created_at, type: 'date'
    indexes :slug, index: :not_analyzed
    indexes :publish, type: 'boolean', index: :not_analyzed
  end
```

Notify the `user_id` and `user_name`, the above definition of mapping method will map the `user.id` to the `user_id`, and `user.name` to `user_name`.

So now in search method, you can do some similar code like
`filter :terms, user_id: params[:search][:user_id]`

Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

One correction to the above, ElasticSearch has dropped the type string and now uses text.